# how to connect between android application and web application using WampServer?

Tags: php, android, client-server

I am trying to program an Android application and made a test for the web service which allows you to send a message to the server and return a string such as `ok`, but there is a problem when sending the message and didn't find an answer.

**My web service Android code:**

```
String line = null;

try{

URL twitter = new URL("http://192.168.1.8:9090/younes_project/younesservices.php?action=001");

URLConnection tc = twitter.openConnection();

BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(tc.getInputStream()));     

  if(line==null){Log.i("------resultat---------"," line ==========nullllllllll" );

  }
else{Log.i("------resultat---------","-----------line =============not nulllllllll" );}
     line = in.readLine();          

}
catch(Exception e){}
```

**my younesservices.php file:**

```
<?php
    if(@($_GET['action'])){
        switch($_GET['action']){
            case "001":
                echo "ok";
                break;
            case "002":
                include("accueil.php");
                break;
            case "003":
                include("point.php");
                break;
        }
    }
?>
```

Configuring the IP address of server WampServer, the file is in httpd.confg

```
Listen 127.0.0.1:9090
Listen 80
```

my IP address ipconfig:

```
 Suffixe DNS propre à la connexion. . . : home
 Adresse IPv6 de liaison locale. . . . .: fe80::529:22f7:8fd4:324c%14
 Adresse IPv4. . . . . . . . . . . . . .: 192.168.1.2
 Masque de sous-réseau. . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
 Passerelle par défaut. . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
```

Comment: you need a [rubber duck for debugging](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) ... then go to lines: `if(line==null){...}else{line=in.readLine();}` and explain it to your duck ...

Comment: you should do some debuggin: can you reach the wamp-server at all (with a browser): make a test-method that just returns "hello" or something. If you have done that, check if you can reach it with your phone/VM 's browser. If you managed that, try if your code can load a page. Etc. Use error logging and show us errors. debug.

Comment: also: format your code (or at least the code in this question).. fix the white-spacing

Comment: i think there is no error in code ... only `line` is never assigned to something other then `null`

Answer (score 0):

Can you access your PHP script from your browser at all? If not try having WAMP SERVER open and ensure that all services are started and the tray icon is green, then change this line

```
http://192.168.1.8:9090/younes_project/younesservices.php?action=001
```

To

```
http://10.0.2.2:9090/younes_project/younesservices.php?action=001
```

That will be the localhost IP address to open wamp server files, and as mentioned in comments the line

```
  StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
  String data = "";
if(line == null){
       Log.i("------resultat---------"," line ==========nullllllllll" );
        }
        else{ 
             Log.i("------resultat---------","-----------line =============not nulllllllll" );
            }
            line = in.readLine();   

            sb.append(line + "\n");
            in.close();
            data = sb.toString();
            Log.i("---------resultat-------------", data);
```

Then you should see your data print out in the LogCat, which should be `ok`.